# Keep only characters in between two hyphens from a dataframe cell which has comma separated list

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a database for eg.

```
Name    Subset
Apple   -AI-,-BI-A,-XC-,ZX-
Bat     -po-,-IJ-,-IA-B
```

and want to convert it to:

```
Name    Subset
Apple   AI,BI,XC,ZX
Bat     po,IJ,IA
```

i.e removing the first hyphen and removing the second hyphen and charachters following it until next comma appears.

Comment: do you mean `Apple AI,BI,XC,ZX` ?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in second table.

Comment: in the second table I read `AI.BI,XC,ZX`, not `AI,BI,XC,ZX`. is that a typo?

Comment: Also `ZX-` in the first table does not have a leading hyphen, is that a typo? because, in that case there is no second hyphen, so that would be a different case. There you would want all letters before the first hyphen.

Comment: Yes that AI.BI was a typo. The ZX- case is not a typo, there are some cases in my dataset like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, use `extractall` with the `-([^-]+)-` regex to get only the values between dashes. Then `GroupBy.agg` with `','.join` to concatenate the values:

```
df['Subset'] = (df['Subset'].str.extractall(r'-([^-]+)-')[0]
                .groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)
                )
```

output:

```
    Name    Subset
0  Apple  AI,BI,XC
1    Bat  po,IJ,IA
```

To handle the case where the left dash can be missing, use `[-,]+([^-,]+)-`:

```
df['Subset'] = (df['Subset'].str.extractall(r'[-,]+([^-,]+)-')[0]
                .groupby(level=0).agg(','.join))
```

output:

```
    Name       Subset
0  Apple  AI,BI,XC,ZX
1    Bat     po,IJ,I
```

Comment: nice but ZX is missing

Comment: @mozway Is there anything in particular wrong with my answer? I understand it might be slower than yours. But apart from that my answer's also fine, right?

Comment: @Mayank it's a bit complicated but seems OK, I would use a regex after the first split/explode to get the matching values, other than that seems to work ;)

Comment: How can use a conditional if else case here to find first if sigle element of list has two hyphen then use first method, if it has one hyphen then use second.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Series.str.split`, `Series.explode` and `Series.groupby.agg`:

```
In [2193]: df['Subset'] = df.Subset.str.split(',').explode().str.split('-').str[:2].apply(''.join).groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)

In [2194]: df
Out[2194]: 
    Name       Subset
0  Apple  AI,BI,XC,ZX
1    Bat     po,IJ,IA
```